# React update State Array inside of Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently try to update the state object inside of my react class based component.

The problem is that my state is an 2 dimensional array which looks like this:

```
this.state = {
  items: [
    {
      title: 'first depth',
      items: [
        {
          title: 'second depth',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

For updating the first depth of the array inside my state object I use this code:

```
this.setState(({items}) => ({
  items: [
    ...items.slice(0, index),
    {
      ...items[index],
      title: 'new Title',
    },
    ...items.slice(index + 1),
  ],
}));
```

But I cannot update the second depth of the array inside my state.

Does someone has an idea how to update the second depth?

Comment: Hi, do you need to update all elements at once? if not you could just get the second deep item, update its content and then update the main array

Answer (score 2):

create new state by spread, then change inner array by splice:

```
this.setState((oldState) => {
   const newState = {...oldState}; 
   const newItem = { ...newState.items[index],  title:"new Title"};
   newState.items.splice(index, 1,  newItem);
   return newState;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the same pattern, you will need the index of the 2nd depth item you want to change.

```js
this.setState(({items}) => ({
  items: [
    ...items.slice(0, index),
    {
      items: [
        ...items[index].slice(0, indexOf2ndDepth),
        {
          title: 'new Title'
        },
        ...items[index].slice(indexOf2ndDepth + 1),
      ],
      title: 'new Title',
    },
    ...items.slice(index + 1),
  ],
};
}));
```

This can get pretty complex and I recommended you isolate the 2nd depth array first, make changes, and insert it into the 1st depth array

```js
this.setState(({ items }) => {
  const secondDepthArray = [
    ...items[index].slice(0, indexOf2ndDepth),
    {
      title: 'new Title',
    },
    ...items[index].slice(indexOf2ndDepth + 1),
  ];

  return {
    items: [
      ...items.slice(0, index),
      {
        items: secondDepthArray
        title: 'new Title',
      },
      ...items.slice(index + 1),
    ],
  };
});
```

Answer (score -1):

To do that you can store your state in variable  and update your array after that use prev prevState to update  your State your array

Answer (score -1):

You can clone new array from state

```
const newItems = [...this.state.items]
// And then modify it
```

So if you want to update array just setState

```
this.setState({items: newItems})
```

Comment: Spread is a shallow clone, you need to clone each nested array also to answer the ops question.